# Can the smart card authentication process treated as a user digitally signed the content(and then get verified on the server)?

Tags: .net, authentication, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, digital-signature

I know the answer is probably no, but I can't convince myself either way.

The authentication was triggered by certain event (like approving button) on the form. In the process of smart card authentication using client certificate authentication (in IIS), user was asked to use their PIN (private key) and after authentication, a certificate information is accessible (through x509). If I place an image of the user signature on the form after authentication, can that be served as a digital signature?

so can the authentication process be treated as signing (on empty content) and quickly verified by the server? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some answer elsewhere. In case anyone is interested 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41777/can-the-client-certificate-authentication-process-treated-as-a-user-digitally-si